# ECN support in delay-based CC

Tags: networking, tcp

Is Explicit Congestion Notification (**ECN**) limited to loss-based Congestion Control (**CC**) algorithms, or is ECN supported regardless of CC algorithm (e.g. *TCP Vegas*)?